# Fetch all nodes of html and apply a new coustom Id to each and every node

Tags: php, parsing

I am working to fetch all nodes of parsed HTML for that I am working on Simple HTML DOM Parser I am able to get all div or all span tags with this

```
foreach($html->find("div") as $e)
{
   //here I got all div tags which are contained in html object but I want all tags not divs
   //then I am addin coustom attribute like this way
  $e->setattribute("My_id","abc");
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I know nothing about that class, but would find("") or find("*") return anything?

Comment: I tried  find("*") but not workin :(

Comment: $html->find('text') will get you all blocks containing text. Is that good enough?

Comment: thanks for you replay @donutdan4114 but I want to apply ids on all tags not only text containing blocks.

Comment: You COULD do a tree traversal. $tree = $html->find('html'). Then you can get the children using $tree->children. Loop through each children, finding more children, etc.. You could have a recursive function to traverse through the DOM and create IDs for those elements on the fly. [source](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: yes I am going to try it. and get back to you in 5 min.

Comment: yes It working but I have to do in recursion so I can get the deepest children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that I have just added phpquery library.

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($html);
$ul = pq('*');
$i = 1;
foreach($ul as $li) {
   pq($li)->attr('sws_id', $i);
    $i++;
}
```

to install phpQuery you can find this library via git follow this url.

https://github.com/rrmodi88/phpQuery